# Succedd to compile project in react-create-app, but when trying to deploy to heroku - it fails

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, create-react-app

i finished to build a react app using create-react-app.
when starting the development server - it succedd , i can run the app without problem.
but when i am trying to deploy to heroku. it says:
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

```
   ./src/components/BgHeader.js
   Cannot find file '../images/main/resBg.jpg' in './src/components'.
```

It can't find the images files , which is weired - because the path is 100% correct and the development server runs without any problem!
I tried to reset the VS CODE, i tried to delete/re-create the heroku project,nothing helps..

Comment: Can you trying building it in local by running `npm run build` ?

Comment: @vishalsaugat yes , i can , build succedd when typing npm run build

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
the images in git were JPG while in the folder they were jpg.
Git ignored the case sensitive, so i had to rename all the images in GIT to .jpg (lower case).